# Wrong Model property name in view not notified by visual studio debugger?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

To explain my problem, an example is better.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 controller action who return a view with an object as a Model.
This object, contains some business properties used by the view like a list of contacts, for example.

If i call a property of my object in the view (from Model.) and, after that, I change this property name, the debugger of visual studio say nothing.
However, this one should alert me that I try to load, in the view, a property who doesn't exist !

Moreover, when i compile this project, it passes until i try to render the view !

Is there a way to check that from visual studio ?

Thank's by advance !

Comment: After you change the property name, isn't the wrong name underlined with a red squiggle? Or maybe you expected to get a compile-time error?

Comment: Yes but you have only the notification when the view aspx file opened in visual studio. no way to check this without opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [enable compilation](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-visual-studio/) of your ASP.NET MVC views by putting the following in your `.csproj`:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

This way you will get a compile-time error.

Comment: Exactly what i need ! You can't imagine how much bugs i will detect with this ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile in `Release` mode to highlight all deal breakers. takes a bit longer to compile but catches everything, right down to properties in Views and even takes you to the line in the View that's causing the problem(s).